# How can I set up a custom pattern for an XSD date?

Tags: xml, date, xsd, format

I am trying to put the following pattern into the XSD schema:
January 1, 2020

I tried playing around with the pattern tag but I couldn't even validate the simplest dd/mm/yyyy format.
Is there a way to implement the pattern above and only the months' can be there and not just a simple string?
I also tried to base it as a string and put a pattern restriction on that but I could not figure out how I could implement that.

I am using XML 1.0

My XSD:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="ReleaseYearDesc">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:gYear">
      <xs:minInclusive value="1900"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="2020"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="DateAddedDesc">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
      <xs:pattern value=""/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="DatesDescription">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ReleaseYear" type="ReleaseYearDesc" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="DateAdded" type="DateAddedDesc" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

My desired result:

```
  <Dates>
    <ReleaseYear>2020</ReleaseYear>
    <DateAdded>September 9, 2019</DateAdded>
  </Dates>
```

I am calling the element below in my XSD file, I don't think it's necessary to include that part.

Comment: (1) What is your XSD version: 1.0 or 1.1? (2) Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: See the edit, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Based on the correct answer my final pattern was the following:
January(\s){1}([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]),(\s){1}((19[0-9][0-9])|20[01][0-9]|2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot describe the separate parts of your string using built-in XML Schema simple types. A simple type definition needs to describe the entire value. The only approach here is to create a restriction of xs:string using pattern facets.

My standard approach when I encounter something like this is:

1. Understand the problem
2. Understand the language/tool
3. Find a solution to the problem using the language/tool

In your case, the language is XML Schema, and the relevant part of the language specification is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-pattern

> > *Schema Representation Constraint: Multiple patterns*
> > If multiple  element information items appear as [children] of a , the [value]s should be combined as if they appeared in a single ·regular expression· as separate ·branch·es.
> > *Note*:  It is a consequence of the schema representation constraint Multiple patterns (§4.3.4.3) and of the rules for ·restriction· that ·pattern· facets specified on the same step in a type derivation are ORed together, while ·pattern· facets specified on different steps of a type derivation are ANDed together.

In other words, you are allowed to specify multiple pattern facets on a simple type restriction, and they will be treated as *alternative* valid patterns.

I think something like this should work:

```xsd
<xs:simpleType name="customDateFormat">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="January +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="February +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="March +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="April +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="May +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="June +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="July +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="August +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="September +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="October +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="November +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="December +[0-9], +[0-9]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The patterns allow multiple spaces between the parts, but you can adjust the pattern if necessary.